# how to use sincedb in logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have thousands of logs files and it gets downloaded everyday. I am using logstash and ElasticSearch for parsing, indexing and searching.

Now I am using file input plugin for reading downloaded files and parsing it. I have not set `sincedb_path` so its storing in `$HOME`. But the problem is it reads log files for just one day. Here is my configuration for input:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/logs/downloads/apacheLogs/env1/**/*"
    type => "env1"
    exclude => "*.gz"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
  file {
    path => "/logs/downloads/appLogs/env2/**/*"
    type => "env2"
    exclude => "*.gz"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you always specified `start_position => "beginning"`, or was there a time when you might have run without that? It only makes a difference the first time Logstash spots a file: it will start reading from the end of the file (default), or the beginning (if set). If a file read from the end is never updated, it will appear to never be read at all.

Comment: yes i always specified `start_position => "beginning"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is apparently caused by a bug in the File handler.

When File{} input method reads a log file, the last byte processed is being saved and periodically copied out to the `sincedb` file. While you can set the file to be `/dev/null` if you want, Logstash reads the file only during start up and uses the information from table in memory after.

The problem is that the table in memory indexes position by inode, and is never pruned, even if it detects that a given file no longer exists.  If you delete a file and then add a new one -- even if it has a different name -- it may well have the same inode number, and the File handler will think it is the same file.

If the new file is larger, then the handler will only read from the previous max byte onwards and update the table.  If the new file is smaller, then it seems to think the file was somehow truncated, and may start processing again from the default position.

As a result, the only way to handle things is to set `sincedb` to be `/dev/null`, and then restart logstash (causing the internal table to be lost) and then all the files matching the pattern will be re-read from the beginning - and this has problems as well, since some of the files may not be new.

Comment: The new `ignore_older` option can provide a workaround.  If your files rotate daily, then having `ignore_older=86400` (the default) will stop you re-reading old files.  You still need to use `sincedb=/dev/null` though as the problem with inodes not being pruned remains

Answer (score 1):

Do logstash have any error message?

One possible problem is in linux system, there is limitation for number of opened files for every user. Logstash will open all the files which in the logstash input path(/logs/downloads/apacheLogs/env1/**/*). Therefore, when your log files are over the limitation, logstash can't open any new log file and reads them. You can check your system settings (/etc/security/limits.conf).

Edit:
After you have modify the config file, you need to logout and login again.

Comment: I checked the logstash log file. No error is being thrown. And I have set my file limit to 50,000.

Comment: If there are not any error, you can try to remove start_position => "beginning". In my experience,your file api configuration do not have any mistake.

Comment: Can you please explain me a little more. What happens when I remove start_position => "beginning"?

Comment: From the information your post at here, I have try my best to think about any situation I met before. So for my suggestion you can try any  configuration to figure out this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of "ignore_older". By default it is set to 86400 i.e, 1 day. So if the files that are present in the path provided are older than 1 day(not modified), it is ignored.

You can set ignore_older => 0
so that all files are read.

You can file more on https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, but I had a similar problem. Needed to read the file, delete it and wait for a new one next day, but sadly they would have the same inode. So what Steve Shipway said is true, there is in-memory storage of sincedb also, but I've been able to achieve this in 7.10 version with

```
sincedb_clean_after => 0
```

Seems like this option actually cleans both, sincedb file and in-memory storage of information and the file with the same inode is going to get read, there is no need to make /dev/null a sincedb path.