# input file start_position => "beginning" doesn't work even after deleting .sincedb files

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

Version: ElasticSearch-5.2.1/Logstash-5.2.1/Kibana-5.2.1
OS: Windows 2008

I've just started working on the ELK Stack & am facing some problems loading data
I've got the following .json code

```
input { 
   file {  
      path => "D:\server.log" 
      start_position => beginning 
    } 
} 
filter { 
   grok { 
     match => ["message","\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\] %{GREEDYDATA:log_message}"] 
   } 
} 
output { 
   elasticsearch { 
     hosts => "localhost:9200" 
    } 
 }
```

I've deleted the *.sincedb* files

And yet when I extract log info in Kibana, I can see data starting only since I first parsed. I've got data worth 2-3 months in my log file.

Comment: can you share your log file ?

Comment: @SahilGulati I am a newbie to this. How do I generate logs?
I couldn't find a location where they already existed...

Answer (score 2):

What if you have your *file input* as such, where you're missing out the [ignore older](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-ignore_older) which actually will stop you re-reading the old files plus you're missing out the [since db path](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-sincedb_path) property I believe. You could have a look up on this answer by [@Steve Shipway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25006705/1338588) for a better explanation on having these two properties within your *file input*.

So your `input` could look something like this:

```
input { 
   file {  
      path => "D:\server.log" 
      start_position => "beginning" <-- you've missed out the quotes here
      ignore_older => 0 
      sincedb_path => "/dev/null" 
    } 
}
```

**Note** that setting `sincedb_path` to */dev/null* will make the files read from the beginning, every time which isn't a good solution at all. But then deleting the **.sincedb** file should work I reckon. If you really want to pick up lines from where you left off, you really need the **.sincedb** file to hold into the last position which got updated lastly. You could have a look on [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#_tracking_of_current_position_in_watched_files) for a detailed illustration.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @Darth_Vader

I read the links you've mentioned
and tried out the input file 
but unfortunately it still reads from the 1st time I started to use the ELK stack
and not from the start of the log file
First time I used ELK Stack was 18th Feb
First log entry is of 31st Jan

Please help
Thanks
P

Answer (score 2):

in my case, when you enter `systemctl restart logstash`, even if you have deleted the sincedb file, logstash before the process closes save a new sincedb file and then closes.

if you want really read file from beginning, you should:

1. stop the logstash service: `sudo systemctl stop logstash`
2. delete sincedb file from `/var/lib/logstash/plugins/inputs/file` or `/usr/share/logstash/data/plugins/input/file` directory
3. start the logstash service: `sudo systemctl start logstash`